# HBase logcleaner does not delete the oldWALs files

Tags: hdfs, hbase, hadoop2, cloudera-cdh

In my lab, HBase archive Write Ahead Logs i.e. oldWALs files are not deleted and oldWALs directory is growing quickly in terabyte.

```
8.1 K    24.4 K  /hbase/.hbase-snapshot
0        0       /hbase/.hbck
0        0       /hbase/.tmp
3.6 K    10.7 K  /hbase/MasterProcWALs
900.3 M  7.1 G   /hbase/WALs
3.4 G    10.3 G  /hbase/archive
0        0       /hbase/corrupt
938.7 G  2.8 T   /hbase/data
42       84      /hbase/hbase.id
7        14      /hbase/hbase.version
4.9 T    4.9 T   /hbase/oldWALs
0        0       /hbase/staging
```

Tried below options to clean up; but no luck.

1. Updated replication is false at hbase master and restarted
2. Decrease ttl to 1sec
3. No peers
4. Multiple times restarted the HBase component.

Answer (score 1):

I tried below properties then it is delete around 1 terabyte of oldWALs files.

```
hbase.cleaner.scan.dir.concurrent.size=1 (default is 0.25). 
hbase.oldwals.cleaner.thread.size=10 ( default is 2)
```